# API couldn't insert data to database

Tags: php, postgresql, api, heroku

This api works perfectly in case of localhost. Even in live server reading of data from database is working fine. I deployed this in heroku. Here this api using Heroku PostgreSQL as database.

https://trybd.herokuapp.com/admins/read.php you can read data from database using this url.

This is the class and here in create function for inserting data to the database.

```
<?php
class Admin{
 
    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "admins";
 
    // object properties
    public $userid;
    public $pass;
    public $email;
    public $institute;
    public $name;
    public $contact_no;
    public $address;
    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }
function create(){
        // query to insert record
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    userid=:userid, pass=:pass, institute=:institute, email=:email, name=:name, contact_no=:contact_no, address=:address;";

        // prepare query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
     
        // sanitize
        $this->userid=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->userid));
        $this->pass=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pass));
        $this->institute=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->institute));
        $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
        $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
        $this->contact_no=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->contact_no));
        $this->address=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->address));
     
        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(":userid", $this->userid);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pass", $this->pass);
        $stmt->bindParam(":institute", $this->institute);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $this->email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":contact_no", $this->contact_no);
        $stmt->bindParam(":address", $this->address);
        // execute query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
         
    }
}
```

This is the page where I'm calling create function of admin class.

```
<?php

    // required headers
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
     
    // get database connection
    include_once '../config/database.php';
     
    // instantiate product object
    include_once '../objects/teacher.php';


    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
     
    $teacher = new Teacher($db);
    // set product property values
    $teacher->userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $teacher->pass = $_POST['password'];
    $teacher->admin_id = $_POST['admin_id'];
    $teacher->email = $_POST['email'];
    $teacher->institute = $_POST['institute'];
    $teacher->name = $_POST['name'];
    $teacher->contact_no = $_POST['contact_no'];
    $teacher->address= $_POST['address'];
 
    // create the product
    if($teacher->create()){
 
        // set response code - 201 created
        http_response_code(201);
 
        // tell the user
        echo json_encode("Registration Successful");
    }
 
    // if unable to create the product, tell the user
    else{
        // set response code - 503 service unavailable
        http_response_code(503);
 
        // tell the user
        echo json_encode("Registration Failed");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to create a new cluster in MongoDB Cloud Atlas (https://www.mongodb.com/cloud) and connect it to your app, so it will works in heroku production ?

Comment: What are you connection parameters? I may have missed it but I do not see where you `COMMIT` the data? Are there any errors returned to you or in the Postgresql logs?

Comment: @Adrian there is no error. Even the api getting data perfectly but somehow it couldn't insert in database

Comment: That gets back to are you doing a `COMMIT` anywhere? If not the `INSERT` will not survive the session.

Comment: @JeromeW I can read data from database by calling api and in case of create api this file getting data perfectly so I think there is no need to switch database.

Comment: @Adrian no. I'm not commiting anywhere. Could you please say it in more details

Comment: I don't use PHP, so I will not much help with the details. You will need to go to the docs for whatever Postgresql driver you are using and see what they say.